# Laplace differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

Solve $$y''' - 3y'' + 3y' -y = t^2e^t $$

when $$y''(0) = -2\,\quad,  \quad y'(0) = 0\quad,  \quad y(0) = 1$$

EDIT:
I arrived at $$y = 2/(s-1)^6 - 1/(s-1)^3$$

EDIT2: Turns out I forgot to multiply the s terms

Comment: solve in the first step the equation $$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=0$$

Comment: make the Ansatz $$y=e^{\lambda t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Apply

**Laplace Transform of the Derivative**
$$\mathcal{L}[y^{(n)}](s)=s^nY(s)-s^{n-1}y(0)-s^{n-2}y'(0)-\cdots s\,y^{(n-2)}(0)-y^{(n-1)}(0)$$

**Derivatives of the Laplace Transform**

$$\mathcal{L}[{t^ny(t)}](s)=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}(Y(s))$$

**Table of Laplace Transforms**
$$\mathcal{L}[{e^t}](s)=\frac{1}{s-1}$$